# Thread is always running, can't stop

Tags: java

I want to make a test, two thread, one thread is changing the value, another thread use a while to wait the first thread, and then break and finish.But the question is the waiting thread is always running, can' stop any more. Another question is when i open the code of "System.out.println(i + " run");", all the thread can work normally, it's so strange.

```
import java.util.Date;

public class ThreadTestTwo {
    public int a = 0, b = 0,c = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new Date()+"start");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        new ThreadTestTwo().start(i);
        if(i % 100000 == 0){
            System.out.println(i/100000);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(new Date()+"finish");
}

public void start(final int i){
    Thread readThread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                if(c == 1){
                    b = a;
//                      System.out.println(i+", set b "+a);
                    break;
                }
//                  System.out.println(i + " run");
            }
        }
    };
    Thread writeThread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            a = 1;
            c = 1;
        }
    };
    writeThread.setName("mywrite");
    readThread.setName("myread");
    System.out.println(i+" start");
    writeThread.start();
    readThread.start();

    try {
        writeThread.join();
        readThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(i+" end");
    if(b != 1)
        throw new RuntimeException("b = "+b);
}

}
```

Comment: The console log is:

`181 start
181 end
182 start
182 end
183 start
183 end
184 start
184 end
185 start
185 end
186 start
186 end
187 start
187 end
188 start`


And use jstack to see the thread state that the readThread is running in the line of "if(c == 1){"

Comment: Make `a` and `c` volatile or use correct synchronization when sharing fields between threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The writes of one thread are NOT guaranteed to be seen for another thread unless the variables are marked as volatile or otherwise the transactions need to handled using synchronization or explicit locking**

In your case, a,b,c are the instance variables accessed by multiple threads and the reader thread caches the values and so it doesn't see the writer thread's flushed value.

Please refer the below link for more details:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to read more on Threads. Here it is an interesting document from O'really: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001805/ch09.html

As for your implementation, you should be aware that the modification of one variable by a thread may not be seen by a reader thread. To combat that either use `synchronised` gets and sets, access the variables inside a synchronized block, or use an `AtomicReference`. You could also use a `Lock` such as `ReantrantLock`.

Also, if you have two threads, in which the first is waiting for the input of the second, you could use the `wait()` inside a `synchronized` block for the first, so that the second could `notify()` the first one when it finishes its job.

Something like this:

```java
import java.util.Date;

public class ThreadTestTwo {

    private int a = 0, b = 0,c = 0;
    private final Object lock = new Object(); 
    //Any object is good as a lock, and for a simple case as this it's fine.
     //This object will work as a monitor for the synchronized blocks.

    public void start(final int i){
        Thread readThread = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {

                synchronized ( lock ) {
                    try {
                        while( c != 1 ) {
                            lock.wait();
                        }
                    }
                    catch ( InterruptedException ex ) {
                        //Exception handling
                    }

                    b = a;
                }

                //System.out.println(i + " run");

            }
        };

        Thread writeThread = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {

                synchronized ( lock ) {
                    a = 1;
                    c = 1;
                    lock.notify();
                }

            }
        };

        writeThread.setName("mywrite");
        readThread.setName("myread");
        System.out.println(i+" start");
        writeThread.start();
        readThread.start();

        System.out.println(i+" end");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Date()+"start");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            new ThreadTestTwo().start(i);
            if(i % 100000 == 0){
                System.out.println(i/100000);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(new Date()+"finish");
    }
}
```

I would say you don't need `join()` with this method. But if want to wait for the second thread to start after the first is finished, you have to use `join()` before starting it. Like this:

```java
    writeThread.start();
    try {
        writeThread.join();
    }
    catch ( InterruptedException ex ) {
        //Exception handling
    }


    readThread.start();
    try {
        readThread.join();
    }
    catch ( InterruptedException ex ) {
        //Exception handling
    }
```

But if you use `join()`, **for this particular case**, I would say you wouldn't need any synchronized blocks or conditions, since the second thread would only start after the death of the first one. Something like this:

```java
public void start(final int i){
    Thread readThread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            b = a;
            //System.out.println(i + " run");

        }
    };

    Thread writeThread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            a = 1;
            c = 1;

        }
    };

    writeThread.setName("mywrite");
    readThread.setName("myread");
    System.out.println(i+" start");


    writeThread.start();
    try {
        writeThread.join();
    }
    catch ( InterruptedException ex ) {
        //Exception handling
    }


    readThread.start();
    try {
        readThread.join();
    }
    catch ( InterruptedException ex ) {
        //Exception handling
    }

    System.out.println(i+" end");
}
```

I hope I have helped.

Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score -1):

It's not a good idea to use an simple int as a signal between threads because it's not thread safe.

So try to use AtomicInteger instead or make your int volatile and see what will happen.

Comment: That is only partially correct. Arithmetic operations may not be thread-safe but reads and writes are atmoic, and defining them as `volatile` disables caching-effects and introduces a happens-before order.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me why the "readThread" can not finish? I can't understand.

Comment: [However, there are actions you can specify that are atomic:

Reads and writes are atomic for reference variables and for most primitive variables (all types except long and double).](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html)

Comment: @tongmutou I recommend reading the [Oracle Tutorial on Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html). Basically, what can happen is that the writing thread only updates its local copy of the variable, not the version in main memory. Also, the reading thread may only read its local copy (cached version) and thus not fetch the version form main memory. Declaring variables as `volatile` will suppress this caching effects on them (this may have a negative performance impact, but is necessary to avoid memory consistency problems).

Comment: @Turing85, but as the write thread exists very soon. Won't him flush all the cached values to the main memory?

Comment: @T.Tony even then, it is not guaranteed that the reading thread reads from main memory. This is exactly what the happens-before principle does: guarantee that all successive reads after a write will see the correct value, always.

Comment: @Turing85 thanks, i think i understand. I try to declaring value c as `volatile`, it's work correctly.